# Delphi Webservice: How to extract xml data of TXMLdata?

Tags: xml, web-services, delphi

I'm trying to get the data from webservice, some values of type string, integer is possible, but tables in xml file are read as TXMLdata. How can I read this or save in xml to use later in ClientDataset? I use WDSLimporter from XE5 and this is a WDSL link:

http://hidroweb.ana.gov.br/fcthservices/mma.asmx?WSDL

[image: TXMLdata]

Comment: in Delphi Help have "Soap.XSBuiltIns.TXMLData.ObjectToSOAP returns the XML for the newly generated node.", but I can´t fill these arguments.

Comment: I haven't tried this but the help also says that the TXMLData type has an XMLNode property that "specifies the SOAP message node's raw XML. Use the contents of XMLNode to obtain the actual XML for the message node". You could assign this to an IXMLNode and then access the XML as a Delphi class.

Comment: Thanks, yesterday on 4:30 am discover the XMLNode that no have in Delphi early versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @J__ suggested you can use the `XMLNode` property of your `TXMLData` to access the underlying `XML`.

Try following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showMessage(GetMMASoap.Bacia.XMLNode.XML);
end;
```

And the result:

[image]

Please take in account I did not add the necessary conditions to avoid AVs in case the `GetMMASoap` or some of its nested objects do not return data. You would have to add those yourself.

Once you have the `XML`, it is up to your needs how to get it into a `TClientDataset` or alternative. Personally I would write a `parser` to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Guillem Vicens, yesterday on 4:30 am discover the XMLNode that no have in Delphi early versions. More one thing, Can I put for example GetMMASoap.Bacia.XMLNode.XML direct in ClientDataset.Filename or a I need to save into Xml before?

Comment: I am afraid you will not be able to do that. `TClientDataset` uses its own schema to save and load from files. That means it will almost surely not be (directly) compatible with your XML data. You will have to parse the XML to load it into the TClientDataset. Check the `TClientDataSet.SaveToFile` and `TClientDataSet.LoadFromFile` help topics for more information.